# What does (#t #f) mean in Scheme function?

Tags: scheme

I got this code from internet and I am not getting the meaning of `(#t #f)` in the last line of the function. Please elaborate on this.

```
(define (equal? S1 S2)
    (cond ((and (not (pair? S1)) (not (pair? S2))) (eqv? S1 S2))
          ((or (not (pair? S1)) (not (pair? S2))) #f)
          ((equal? (car S1) (car S2)) (equal? (cdr S1) (cdr S2))) 
          (#t #f)))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a misuse of the `cond` statement; although it's idiomatic in Common Lisp, in Scheme the equivalent and idiomatic syntax should have been:

```
(else #f)
```

It's just a way to say: if all other conditions fail, then return false. Why it works? well, in a clause that looks like `(#t <anything>)` the `<anything>` expression will always be evaluated, because the condition is true. And that's why `else` should have been used in the first place, to make the intent explicit.

And there's an additional advantage of using `else` here: The interpreter enforces the restriction that `else` can only appear in the last condition, whereas `(#t <anything>)` could appear at any point, leading to potential problems because any condition after it will never be reached.

Comment: @user2864740 I disagree. Fastest Gun in the West is a feature, not a bug: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9758/13